# What counts as an interior square in the Witch House tile?

Tags: cthulhu-hastur

The [rules for Cthulhu!!! Hastur La Vista Baby!](http://www.twilightcreationsinc.com/fileadmin/downloads/cthulhu/Cthulhu_Rules-v4.pdf) cover named buildings:

> If the tile is any other “named building” (e.g. the “Pharmacy” or “Burial Hill”), place one cultist in each interior square (each square inside the building). Then place one bullet or one heart (your choice) in each interior square. For this purpose, “Burial Hill” is a named building.

This is easy enough for buildings that have a street running through the tile, but what qualifies as an interior square for named tiles like the Witch House tile?

Is it just the farthest row from the entrance? Or does it include the doorway, possibly the square to the right of the door, or even the entire farthest two rows?